# PHP file_get_contents changing file name

Tags: php

I need to get a file from the server and I'm doing it like this:

```
file_get_contents($path.$fileName);
```

It works well with most of the files, until I started experiencing some issues in particular cases like the following:

Where the `$path` is a string like this: `"/path/to/app/and/file/folder/"` (not a url but a realpath)

and `$fileName` is: `"PCard__0000_Front_(2).jpg"`

The error I get is:

```
/path/to/app/and/file/folder/PCard__0000_Front_&#40;2&#41;.jpg)
[function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or
directory
```

Now if I call the function with a string: `file_get_contents("/path/to/app/and/file/folder/PCard__0000_Front_(2).jpg")` it works well

Please some advise on what am I doing wrong, I would really like to understand why this happens.

Thanks!

P.S. I have seen some others say to use curl instead but I would really appreciate if someone could shed some light into why this is happening and how can I solve it using file_get_contents no matter how much better the other function could be.

Comment: Are you sure `$path` *always* ends in a trailing slash? Can we get a more realistic copy of the error message?

Comment: Yes, it's actually a constant like the one there, only fileName is a variable and the error does show the slash before the fileName as well

Comment: Are you doing anything else to `$fileName` other than assigning the string `"PCard__0000_Front_(2).jpg"`?

Comment: Nothing, that's pretty much the code there is. That's why I don't understand why with the string it works ok but with the variable it gets modified to its ASCII version

Comment: What does "modified to its ASCII version" mean? Could you show some actual code?

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$path` and `$fileName`, maybe there are characters which don't get shown.

Comment: Wow sorry just realized that when pasting the error at the question it's showing the parentheses (my bad) ... so the error says it doesn't find the file PCard__0000_Front_&#40;2&#41;.jpg note the #40 and 41

Comment: @Mauro Morales: The filename on the error might be escaped at the time it is outputted, this might not be a representative value of your variable. You have to do a `var_dump` on your variables, to see the actual value there.

Comment: Not sure how to edit the post to show the ascii chars like in my previous comment

Comment: here is the var dump (I'll leave the actual path I'm using on my local machine): string(131) "/Users/mauromorales/creative-works/4over4/4over4/shared/assets/img/sales_order_files/order_215449/PCard__0000_Front_(2).jpg"

Comment: positive, as a matter of testing I'm defining the variables in the previous line from the file_get_contents just to make sure there was nothing being done to that string

Comment: I suggest you `var_dump` both path and filename before the erroneous line

Comment: Thanks @Codemonkey it's in my previous comment

Comment: @MauroMorales read my ans below.

Comment: Well, nobody can answer your question with certainty. Your problem is that you are being inexact, in your code, and with your description of the issue here. Besides the htmlescapes that don't appear by itself in variables, you seemingly have extraneous ASCII/UTF-8 sequences in the filename. -- While we could go on and request a `hex2bin()` dump of your actual filename and a `scandir` dump, I think it's best you start over. Recreate the picture, filter filenames from now on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the output of the error message with the filename showing, `PCard__0000_Front_&#40;2&#41;.jpg`

perhaps there's a need for  `urldecode($filename)`

---

**SOLUTION**

As suggested by a comment (thank you) the solution for the proper file name would be

```
html_entity_decode($filename)
```

Comment: thanks this fixed the problem! :)

I did file_get_contents(html_entity_decode($path.$fileName)) and it's working. Thank you so much!

Do you know why now the file downloads as: _Users_mauromorales_creative-works_4over4_4over4_shared_assets_img_sales_order_files_order_215449_PCard__0000_Front_&#40;2&#41; with the entire path and not only filename (I don't mind but it would look better without it)

Comment: Also if you could tell my why the need of it when a variable and not when a string, would be very appreciated ^__^

Comment: not sure but you could do do `file_put_contents` into a proper file name with the data retrieved from `file_get_contents`

Comment: that makes sense. I was thinking about making a copy with a "readable" name every time I got files with such characters, but I wanted people to be able to see their files with their original names so it's easier for them to associate them

Comment: @MauroMorales Well if you want to do that.. you could just stick to how it is now. Then on the front end you could parse out the actual file name and display that, then keep the full path + name in a tooltip when hovering over the short name :)

Comment: :p you are right again ... maybe I should have come to stackoverflow a few hours ago haha ... thanks again man, appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear and obvious.

There is no such file `/path/to/app/and/file/folder/PCard__0000_Front_&#40;2&#41;.jpg`

So, for some reason you are changing the filename from `PCard__0000_Front_(2).jpg` to `PCard__0000_Front_&#40;2&#41;.jpg`.

A solution: **do not** change the filename.

Comment: I'm not changing the $fileName that's why I don't understand it's happening. I can put the string inside the function and it works. define $fileName on the previous line with that string and use the function with $fileName and it gives that output

Comment: @Mauro: Please show actual code instead of describing it, there's too much guessing going on here.

Comment: here it is:  
$fileName=$realPath."shared/assets/img/$path/order_$orderId/".$fileName;
var_dump($fileName);
$data = file_get_contents($fileName);

Comment: @MauroMorales You keep avoiding showing where `$fileName` is originally set. Please show that bit of code.

Comment: sorry @Phil, here is where it's originally set: 

$segments = $this->uri->segment_array();
$fileName = $segments[5];

So I get the file name from the url and go look for it in the server